# Add multiple controllers in "AppEntry" class

Tags: java, actframework

I want to add multiple controller class to a single "AppEntry" class.

I have LoginService, ClientService, ProductService, AuthenticateService controllers and one "MerchandiseServiceApp" with the main() method with Act.start() method.

In most examples I've seen "MerchandiseServiceApp" class extends Controller.Util and has action methods.

How do I call all the above controllers in MerchandiseServiceApp class?

```java
public class LoginService extends Controller.Util {

    @GetAction("/authenicateId")
    public String authenicateId(String id, ActionContext context) {
        ...
    }


public class ClientService extends Controller.Util {

    @GetAction("/client")
    public String getClient(String id, ActionContext context) {
        ...
    }

public class ProductService extends Controller.Util {

    @GetAction("/product")
    public String getProduct(String id, ActionContext context) {
        ...
    }

public class MerchandiseServiceApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Act.start();
    }
```

How do I call all the above controllers in MerchandiseServiceApp class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call controller methods in your `MerchandiseServiceApp` class. Your `MerchandiseServiceApp` class is just an bootup class for your entire application. Once it is started (through the main() method), The request handler methods defined in your other controllers will be registered into the router of actframework and ready for handling incoming request, e.g. `GET /product` or `GET /client` based on the code you put in the question.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What would be the type of implementation would be adequate for use in production for MerchandiseServiceApp?

Comment: @Vuzi sorry I didn't get you. Not sure what "type of implementation" you are talking about